# How does a six-sided ring contrast from a four-sided ring?

Tags: pro-wrestling

Total Nonstop Wrestling (TNA) fans recently voted to have the company bring back a six-sided ring<sub>[(1)](http://www.cagesideseats.com/tna-impact/2014/6/24/5837592/tna-announces-return-of-six-sided-ring-at-upcoming-new-york-impact)</sub> for their wrestlers to perform in.

**How does a six-sided ring contrast from a four-sided ring?** Obviously, one ring has six sides and the other has four sides, but how does this difference change the mechanics of the ring itself? (ie, Does it have more/less give? Is it more/less sturdy? etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The UFC uses the octagon because it gives the fighters more actual floor area to maneuver in. By contrast a boxing ring is square so that one fighter can cut the ring off from the other fighter and force him up against the ropes as efficiently as possible.

For pro-wresting all this means absolutely nothing since it is strictly entertainment and part of entertaining is climbing up on the ring and jumping off the ropes.

Comment: Didn't think about the strategy part you mention in your first paragraph because of the facts you present in your second paragraph. Still interesting.